# Switch in functions and their derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, conditional, assignment

Consider the following simple example:

```
tlist1[a_: "a"] = Switch[a, "a", {1, 2, 3}, "b", {4, 5, 6}];
tfct1[a_: "a", x_] := #[[1]] + #[[2]]*x^#[[3]] &[tlist1[a]];
tfct2[a_: "a", x_] = D[tfct1[a, x], x];
```

What I want to do is to save a set of parameters as a list (tlist1) in order to generate multiple functions from the same pattern (in real, this will be Sellmeier coefficients for the Sellmeier formula). So tfct1 should give me the desired function when I specify `a`. E.g. `tfct1["a",x]=1+2*x^3` or `tfct1["b",x]=4+5*x^6`.

Now, tfct2 uses derivatives (and second-order derivatives, but I skipped that for simplification), and I would like a result like `tfct2["a",x]=6*x^2`and `tfct2["b",x]=30*x^5`. But it should be usable as `tfct2["a",2]=24` or `tfct2["b",2]=960`.

Because of the Switch statement I was using delayed evaluation `:=` in the definition of `tfct1` but this somehow screws up the derivation process.

So, how do I use Switch right like in this example when I would like to use derivatives? Or is there a better way to deal with such things? (still, I would like to use symbols like "a", "b", "c" for my coefficient sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement this as follows:

`tlist1` is essentially a lookup table, so let us use an association:

```
tlist1 = <|"a" -> {1, 2, 3}, "b" -> {4, 5, 6}|>;
```

(If you use Mathematica 9 or earlier, which does not have associations, then simply define `tlist1["a"] = ...; tlist1["b"] = ...`, etc.)

Let us use a slightly different notation for `tfct1`:   `tfct1[a][x]` instead of `tfct1[a,x]`. This way `tfct1[a]` is a function in its own right that can be operated on e.g. by [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html).

```
tfct1[a_] := Function[x, #1 + #2 x^#3] & @@ tlist1[a]
```

Example usage:

```
tfct1["a"]
(* Function[x, 1 + 2 x^3] *)

tfct1["a"][z]
(* 1 + 2 z^3 *)
```

We can also take the derivative:

```
tfct1["a"]'
(* Function[x, 6 x^2] *)

tfct1["a"]'[x]
(* 6 x^2 *)

tfct1["a"]'[2]
(* 24 *)
```

If you still want to define `tfct2`, you can do so as

```
tfct2[a_] := tfct1[a]'
```

Comment: nice, thanks! As it is more comfortable for me, I'll define a `tfct3[a_,x_]:=tfct2[a][x];` to be able to use it as intended. It is somehow bothersome that I have to define one function more (`tfct3`) and I don't completely get why this is necessary, but I have a rough idea.

However, your solution works as well with my definition of `tlist1` using `Switch`. I guess, `Association` is faster?

Comment: @riddleculous In this specific case, `Association` is probably not objectively better (speed is pretty much irrelevant here).  I simply like it better, and find it more "Mathematica-like".  In other contexts, it has clear advantages: it is a separate, modifiable, copyable data structure that is not tied to one symbol name.  For example, what if you want to make this lookup table a parameter of your function?

Comment: makes sense! Insofar thanks for pointing me to that, might need it in the future."Mathematica-likeliness" is a funny parameter, though ;-)

Comment: One could also do: `tfct1 = Function[x, #[[1]] + #[[2]] x^#[[3]]] & /@ tlist1` and `tfct2 = #' & /@ tfct1;` - and use it the same way as your functions. Any comment on which to prefer? I will normally work with only one or two of these association Keys but the functions get very complicated and costly.

Comment: @riddleculous No, that will not work. The resulting `Function`s must only contain formulas, not programming constructs such as `Part`. Otherwise `Derivative` will not work.

Comment: but I tested it and it works

Comment: @riddleculous Maybe I did not understand what you did.  A function generated by filling the slots in `Function[x, #[[1]] + #[[2]] x^#[[3]]]` will always contain `Part`. `Part` is not a mathematical concept and isn't handled by symbolic processing functions.  Can you show me the final result---such a function---that can actually be differentiated without errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54129/discussion-between-riddleculous-and-szabolcs).